# Can't edit the database, Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have an edit form with a text field and an image field where a user can edit and upload new text or a image if he/she wants to. But if the user does not upload a new image I just want to keep the old image in the database.

**My Problem**

The problem is when I hit upload button, I'm redirected to the article page and no error is shown but the DB has not been updated what so ever.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

web.php

```
Route::get('/tests/edit/{id}', 'TestController@edit');
Route::patch('/tests', 'TestController@update');
```

TestController.php

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{ 
    $test = Test::findOrFail($request->id);
    return view('test.edit', ['test' => $test]);
}

public function update(Request $request, Test $test)
{
    $test->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $test->name = $request->name;

    if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        Storage::delete('public/image/' . $test->image); //Delete old image
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/image');
        $test->image = basename($path);
    }

    
    $test->update();

    return redirect('/tests')
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div>
    <form action="/tests" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('patch') }}
            name：<input type="text" name="name" value='{{ $test->name }}'><br>
            image： <input type="file" name="image"><br>
            <input type='submit' value='upload'>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: And the `id` in your patch request is where?

Comment: you haven't passed the `id` for update method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit.blade.php add this :

```
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $test->id }}">
```

TestController.php

```
 use $test->save(); instead of $test->update();
```

Comment: Hey,
Thankyou for your advice!
I tried what you suggested and the problem I have now is when I use $test->save();, a new record is added to the DB instead of old one being edited...
Do you know why this happening?

Comment: Add $test = Test::findOrFail($request->id); top to your update function for fix problem xd

Comment: I was able to successfully edit records! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you.I work on a ordering website with laravel that you can get data from laravel and show it to user and also he can order something from the website and the database will be updated.But, I cannot neither get or update data in database.I work with wampserver, mysql and the problem is solved once I switched to MariaDB instead of mysql in phpmyadmin: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/